# Objective-C - How to get sum of Boleans?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, boolean

Through the code below, I can get an output such as :

`0`

    `1`

    `1`

What I want is to output the sum of these booleans values, in my case the result will be : 
 `2` because we have `0+1+1`

The code [Update] :

> ```
>   -(void)markers{
>         CLLocationCoordinate2D tg = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude);
>         GMSCoordinateBounds *test = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc]initWithPath:path];
>         BOOL test3 = [test containsCoordinate:tg];
>         {
>             if (test3 == 1)
>             {
>   marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude);                     
>             }else if (test3 == 0)
>             {
>   marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0);
>             }
>         }
>     }       
> }
> ```

Comment: I see only one BOOL. Where is other two?

Comment: All you really want to do (I think) is _count_ how many BOOLs are YES (not their "sum").

Comment: If you're after the overall boolean value (e.g. logically ANDing all the BOOLs), you could simply multiply them together, remembering to raise any negative values to zero (0). A negative (BOOL false < 0) multiplied by a negative would give you a positive (BOOL true > 0) which would **not** be what you wanted (i.e. multiplying 2x false BOOLS would result in 'true', which is wrong).

Answer (score 8):

Rather than sum BOOLs, which is counterintuitive, loop over whatever you are using to get the BOOL values, and if you get YES, increment a counter. This will be the number of YESs that you have.

If you have an array of BOOLs, you could just filter the array with a predicate to get the YES values and the length of the resulting array is the number of YESs that you have.

**Edited to add code samples following OP comments**

Incrementing a counter

```
NSUInteger numberOfBools = 0;
CLLocationCoordinate2D tg = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude);
GMSCoordinateBounds *test = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc]initWithPath:path];
if ([test containsCoordinate:tg1]) { ++numberOfBools; }
if ([test containsCoordinate:tg2]) { ++numberOfBools: }
... // other tests here;

// numberOfBools now contains the number of passing tests.
```

**Edited Again, after the full code was added**

```
// snipped code above here
// This is where you add the counter and initialise it to 0
NSUInteger numberOfBools = 0;
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array)
{            
    // Snip more code to this point
    BOOL test3 = [test containsCoordinate:tg];
    {
        if (test3)
        {
        // This is where you increment the counter
        ++numberOfBools;

// Snip more code to the end of the for block
}

// Now numberOfBools shows how many things passed test3
```

Comment: the second of these methods would most likely be quite slow however compared to your first counting method.

Comment: Depends when/where you are getting the BOOLs from. A simple loop and count is fine. But if you have to do it a lot, it __might__ be faster to create a static predicate to run over the list. IIRC, creating a predicate is the expensive bit, they are fast to run.

Comment: @Abizern, can you please provide a code snippet, so I can have a clearer idea, thank you anyway !

Comment: @user3340961 It's hard to give you a code snippet when your code only shows a single test.

Comment: @Abizern - not really, in this case what you are saying is that the array would be resized, and that then the size would be the answer.  The problem with array resizing is that is by itself an EXPENSIVE operation.  I see and will look further at your IIRC, maybe there is a different way they are being implemented :-)

Comment: I don't want to get into an argument about this :) it's just a suggestion of an alternative method of counting. I could also have suggested block based iterations (maybe I should have). And filtering doesn't necessarily have to __resize__ an array, `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` returns a new `NSArray`

Comment: @Abizern, can you please provide a code snippet of only what you are explaining, because I really don't know from where to start. Knowing that in my case, YES = 1 and No = 0. So I really don't know how to count the number of YES or the number of NO.

Comment: Arggh! a postfix increment, kill it with fire.

Comment: @Abizern, thanks a lot for the effort, but I am still stuck with it. I am still getting separate values like `1``1`I can can't NOT add all of them to end up with a certain result. I think for that I should store these boolean values in an array then sum them ? Well, I have done it, but no chance, again getting separate value `0` `1` `1` any tip ?

Comment: @user3340961 I still can't see what you are trying to sum. Please post the full code that is causing you problems, not just the edited highlights.

Comment: @Abizern, I have posted the full code, please check it now.

Comment: @Abizern what I wanna sum is the values generated by test3 boolean that come from the DB, or in other words, distinguishing YES values from NO values, then getting sum of YES.

Comment: @user3340961 I've updated the question again. It's basically what I said in my original answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
int sum = (test3 ? 1 : 0) + (testX ? 1 : 0) + (testY ? 1 : 0);
```

And not so weird variant:

```
#define BOOL_TO_INT(val) ((val) ? 1 : 0)

int sum = BOOL_TO_INT(test3) + BOOL_TO_INT(testX) + BOOL_TO_INT(testY);
```

Comment: This still seems like a weird thing to do, but at least it ensures that the Boolean value ends up as either zero or one.

Comment: I don't know what's weird about this @bdesham, but I agree wholeheartedly with the rest of your comment.

Comment: I was considering `int sum = (!test3 ?: 0) + (!testX ?: 0) + (!testY ?: 0);` but I decided that *was* weird.

Comment: @JamesWebster On second thought, it probably wouldn’t look too weird once you put it in context :-)

Comment: Arggh! a #define, kill it with fire. It would probably be better as a static function: `static inline NSUInteger boolToInteger(BOOL b) { return b ? 1 : 0; }`

Comment: @Abizern, you seem to have an aversion to #defines :P I think this is a good example of where #defines *should* be used.

Comment: Not really - I just think there are better ways to do it, which are safer and even add type safety (which in inline function gives you that a define does not), and considering that the correct use of types is a thread running through the comments here, I think it's valid. Hey, at least I didn't paste a snippet of using a block instead of an inline function. :)

Answer (score 2):

You *can* just add BOOLs since bools are just integers. e.g. :

```
int sum = 0;

CLLocationCoordinate2D tg = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude);
GMSCoordinateBounds *test = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc]initWithPath:path];
BOOL test3 = [test containsCoordinate:tg];
//Obtain bolean values :

BOOL testX = /* other test */;
BOOL testY = /* other test */;

sum = test3 + testX + testY
```

This is a bad idea however, as BOOLs aren't necessarily `1` or `0`. They are `0` and `not 0`

BOOL is just a typedef-ed char: `typedef signed char BOOL;` `YES` and `NO` are 1 and 0, but `BOOL variable = 2` is perfectly valid

For example:

```
- (int) testX
{
    if(inState1) return 1;
    if(inState2) return 2;

    else return 0;
}

BOOL textXResult = [self testX]; //Might return 2, this is still equivalent to YES.
```

The best solution is to iterate your BOOLs and instead count the number of YESes.

Comment: (The Objective-C type) `BOOL` is *not* 0 or not 0. It is `NO` (`==0`) or `YES` (`==1`). This is defined. Anyway it is still a bad idea for a different reasons: BOOLs are *implemented* as integers, but this is not defined. Therefore the sum of a `BOOL` object with a `BOOL` object is a `BOOL` object according to usual C rules and will have an invalid value, if both `BOOL` objects are `YES` (`==1`).

Comment: You've misunderstood what I wrote. Any BOOL that `is zero` is NO/false, and BOOL that is `not zero` is YES/true.

Comment: You could write BOOL test3 = [test containsCoordinate:tg]!=0; to make sure it's 0 or 1. But I think that storing a value different from 0 or 1 in a BOOL is a logic mistake, even if it's allowed by the language.

Comment: @James Webster No, I did not misunderstood that. And it is not correct, that a BOOL object equals YES, if it is not zero. Objective-C's BOOL is not C's _Bool.

Comment: I tried this for my book million of times. I'm not wrong. Did you try it? `BOOL a = 2; NSLog(@"%d", a); NSLog(@"%d", a==YES);` outputs 2 and 0. This only works with **C's _Bool**.

Comment: You're twisting what I said in my answer, I didn't say `non-zero is equivalent to YES`. I said `They are 0 and not 0` meaning a BOOL equal to zero evaluates to false: `BOOL a = 0; if (a) NSLog(@"a is true);`. Any non-zero value evaluates to true: `BOOL b = 65; if (a) NSLog(@"a is true);`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to assume that if any one value is false, then the entire array is false, so, loop over the array until a false value is found, then break:

```
BOOL retval = true;  //return holder variable

/*'boolsNumArray' is an NSArray of NSNumber instances, converted from BOOLs:

    //BOOL-to-NSNumber conversion (makes 'boolsNumArray' NSArray, below)!
    '[myNSArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:yourNextBOOL]]' 

*/
for(NSNumber* nextNum in boolsNumArray) {
    if([nextNum boolValue] == false) {
        retval = false;
        break;
    }
}

return retval;
```