# Objective-C, How to count the number of TRUE booleans?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Through the code below, I can get an output such as :

`0`

    `1`

    `1`

This line is generating booleans coming from an external DB (You can check it inside the full code below): 
`BOOL test3 = [test containsCoordinate:tg];`

### The Problem :

I want to count the number of TRUE booleans generated by the BOOL line stated before; for example outputting, how many `1` are found when that line was executed.

### The code :

> ```
>   -(void)markers{
> NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/api/s.php"];
> data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];   
> NSError *error;
> NSMutableArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
> if (error != nil)
> {
>     NSLog(@"Could not fetch data !");
> }    
> NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&sensor=false", coordi, f_query]];
> NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];
> NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];      
> id array2 = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"routes"];
> if([array2 count] > 0) {
>     NSDictionary *routes = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"routes"][0];
>     NSDictionary *route = [routes objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
>     NSDictionary *legs = [routes objectForKey:@"legs"][0];
>     NSString *overview_route = [route objectForKey:@"points"];
>     CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
>     for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array)
>     {            
>         location.latitude = [dictionary[@"latitude"] floatValue];
>         location.longitude = [dictionary[@"longitude"] floatValue];
>         CLLocationCoordinate2D tg = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude);
>         GMSCoordinateBounds *test = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc]initWithPath:path];
>         BOOL test3 = [test containsCoordinate:tg];
>         {
>             if (test3 == 1)
>             {
>    polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.259 green:0.698 blue:0.894 alpha:1.0];
>   marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude);                     
>             }else if (test3 == 0)
>             {
>   polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.647 green:0.839 blue:0.016 alpha:0.7];
>   marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0);
>             }
>         }
>     }       
> }
> ```

I have spent a whole day on searching how to do it, but no chance :s
Any idea on how to solve it ? 
P.S. a code snippet explaining the idea will be very helpful.

Comment: why don't you have a 'int count' and increase it by one every time test3 is YES

Comment: No, it is Outputting `1` each time the coordinates are found within the needed boundaries, increasing by one will NOT give the desired result.

Comment: Duplicate of your previous question [Objective-C - How to get sum of Boleans?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22226656/1717391)

Comment: why are you asking the same question, didn't you get an answer before ?

Comment: As @Emmanuel states, you've asked this question before and had quite a few replies that should help you solve your problem. Reposting essentially the same question seems a bit futile.

Comment: @Emmanuel Is totally NOT the wanted answer.

Comment: "Totally not the wanted answer"? I spent time explaining it to you, edited it twice with code after you asked me to and the you accept the answer here that is just slightly different from mine.  Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To Understand as Simple manner:**

```
int trueCount = 0;
int falseCount = 0;


for (<#initialization#>; <#condition#>; <#increment#>) {

  BOOL test3 = [test containsCoordinate:tg];

    if (test3) {

        trueCount++;
    }
    else{

        falseCount++;
    }

}

NSLog(@"True : %i",trueCount);
NSLog(@"False : %i",falseCount);
```

**Implementation:**

```
-(void)markers{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/api/s.php"];
    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
    if (error != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not fetch data !");
    }
    NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&sensor=false", coordi, f_query]];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
    id array2 = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"routes"];
    if([array2 count] > 0) {
        NSDictionary *routes = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"routes"][0];
        NSDictionary *route = [routes objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
        NSDictionary *legs = [routes objectForKey:@"legs"][0];
        NSString *overview_route = [route objectForKey:@"points"];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D location;

        int trueCount = 0;
        int falseCount = 0;


        for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array)
        {
            location.latitude = [dictionary[@"latitude"] floatValue];
            location.longitude = [dictionary[@"longitude"] floatValue];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D tg = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude);
            GMSCoordinateBounds *test = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc]initWithPath:path];
            BOOL test3 = [test containsCoordinate:tg];

            if (test3) {

                trueCount++;
            }
            else{

                falseCount++;
            }



            {
                if (test3 == 1)
                {
                    polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.259 green:0.698 blue:0.894 alpha:1.0];
                    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude);
                }else if (test3 == 0)
                {
                    polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.647 green:0.839 blue:0.016 alpha:0.7];
                    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0);
                }
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"True : %i",trueCount);
        NSLog(@"False : %i",falseCount);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `int` variable and increment it whenever you get `TRUE` value of the `BOOL` variable.

Suppose, for the problem

let's say

```
int i = 0;
```

Then whenever you get the `TRUE` value for it, increment the value of `i`

```
BOOL test3 = [test containsCoordinate:tg];
if(test3)
{
  ++i;
  NSLog(@"The value of i is : %d", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, before your for loop, you can initialize a counter value and increase it each time you find a positive result:

```
- (void) marker
        {
            int numberOfHits = 0; 
            for(NSdictionnary * items in array)
            { 
                BOOL test3 = [test containsCoordinate:tg];
                numberOfHits += test3;

                /*...*/
            }
        }
```